# Installer class not being called - Visual Installer

Tags: c#

I added two custom action to installer set InstallerClass to true and I'm overriding these custom actions (Commit , Rollback) in installer class but this methods are not being called.

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class Installer : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Message Box");
    }
    
    public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Primary ouput is set to correct dll? Are you testing it freshly, meaning no previous installation was done?

Comment: Yes, primary output is set correct. What do you mean no previous installation ? No I installed the application before but now I want to add methods in the installer

Comment: Uninstall that and try freshly, the issue could be that msi is not replacing old dll or .exe because it has same version, and obviously methods are no called, because there isn't one in old dll/.exe

Comment: I did, nothing changed, still can't the functions

Comment: In constructor of installer you should have InitializeComponent(); called, which is added by default, but seems like you removed it

Comment: Even with the constructor , nothing happening

Comment: Are you rebuilding both project and then setup project?

Comment: Sure, I'm working on vsto application. I don't know if this make any sense why installer is not being called